# How to create events in calender Android

Tags: android, events, android-calendar

Iam trying to create a calender by following the given tutorial http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog
but i want to add some modification to this code.
my exact need is , 
I have a string array , it contain some dates. i want to mark these dates into my calender
and when i click a particular date ,it will become marked, and when i click again it is unmarked, also i want to get the marked dates.
how this is possible. I am very new in android development... this is my first question in stack overflow .. please encourage me... please give me a solution..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Welcome to SO, but people on SO will be more likely to help you work towards an end result rather than just post a completed code solution for you.

Comment: ya i know..i followed that tutorial and create a calendar.upto its ok.

Comment: please give me any idea, from which function, i can mark some dates in that calendar...and when clicking again, it become unmarked